# MIDL error MIDL2337: unsatisfied forward declaration : _Bool

Tags: c++, com, midl

How can trying to build a COM in Visual studio2015 with the following code.
MIDL: error MIDL2337: unsatisfied forward declaration: _Bool
Error of me will fail out.

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";


#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

[uuid("B60DAB85-864C-4C5F-82BF-414AE59B1F1F"), object]
interface ISampleCOM : IUnknown
{
    [propget,
        helpstring("Get NowTime.")] HRESULT GetNowTime(
            [out, retval] time_t* ReturnVal);

}

[uuid("F2544169-985E-4F49-99AD-D51D8C93F5C4")]
coclass SampleCOM
{
    interface ISampleCOM;
}
```

Do you have any good workaround?

Comment: You can't generally include C or C++ headers into IDL. MIDL is not a C compiler, it doesn't understand all C constructs. Drop the `#include`s, and use a `long` or `hyper` or similar in place of `time_t`.

Comment: C99 has been ignored too long to make `_Bool` a suitable interop type.  The only one you can count on to be well supported by other language runtimes is `VARIANT_BOOL`.  You also can't use `time_t`, it has Y2K38 disaster issues and its size is not guaranteed.  Trickier to solve, consider `DATE`.

Comment: thank you.
Try doing the `time_t` to `long`.